# How to pass a list of values for the IN clause of a text() query?

Tags: python, sql-server, sqlalchemy

```
args = [112210104, 112012523]
raw_sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN :values" 
query = sqlalchemy.text(raw_sql).bindparams(values=tuple(args))
cnxn_gw.engine.execute(query)
```

I am trying to pass a list as a parameter through SQL Alchemy, but I'm being met with the following error

```
DBAPIError: (pyodbc.Error) ('HY004', '[HY004] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid SQL data type (0) (SQLBindParameter)')
[SQL: SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN ?]
[parameters: ((112210104, 112012523),)]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/dbapi)
```

The code I tried is the answer from multiple threads on this topic, however I cannot get it to work on my end.

Comment: You can't send list parameters like that, no. I don't think SQLAchemy supports it, but using pyodbc (upon which SQLAlchemy builds) have you considered making use of Table Value Parameters to send iterable data? As the name suggests, a TVP is a table, so instead of using it in an `IN` operator you'd `JOIN` it to your table to filter the rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `expanding=True` and it seems to work.  I only tested it with postgresql.  You can set the type but it seems to work without the type for integers.

Docs: [sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam.params.expanding](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam.params.expanding)

#### Example code

```py
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session, declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import (
    create_engine,
    Integer,
    String,
)
from sqlalchemy.sql import text, bindparam

Base = declarative_base()

engine = create_engine(f"postgresql+psycopg2://{username}:{password}@/{db}", echo=True)


metadata = Base.metadata

class Thing(Base):
    __tablename__ = "things"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String)

metadata.create_all(engine)


ids = []
with Session(engine) as session, session.begin():
    thing_a = Thing(name="a")
    thing_b = Thing(name="b")
    session.add_all([thing_a, thing_b])
    session.flush()
    ids.append(thing_a.id)
    ids.append(thing_b.id)

with engine.connect() as conn:
    raw_sql = "SELECT * FROM things WHERE id IN :ids"
    stmt = text(raw_sql).bindparams(bindparam("ids", type_=Integer, expanding=True))
    for row in conn.execute(stmt, {"ids":ids}).all():
        print (row[0], row[1])


with engine.connect() as conn:
    raw_sql = "SELECT * FROM things WHERE id IN :ids"
    stmt = text(raw_sql).bindparams(bindparam("ids", expanding=True))
    for row in conn.execute(stmt, {"ids":ids}).all():
        print (row[0], row[1])
```

#### Output of last 2 `engine.connect()` blocks.

```
2023-01-12 21:13:58,536 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine BEGIN (implicit)
2023-01-12 21:13:58,538 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO things (name) VALUES (%(name)s) RETURNING things.id
2023-01-12 21:13:58,538 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00020s] ({'name': 'a'}, {'name': 'b'})
2023-01-12 21:13:58,540 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine COMMIT
2023-01-12 21:13:58,566 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT * FROM things WHERE id IN (%(ids_1)s, %(ids_2)s)
2023-01-12 21:13:58,566 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00024s] {'ids_1': 1, 'ids_2': 2}
1 a
2 b
2023-01-12 21:13:58,567 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT * FROM things WHERE id IN (%(ids_1)s, %(ids_2)s)
2023-01-12 21:13:58,567 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00026s] {'ids_1': 1, 'ids_2': 2}
1 a
2 b
```