# Getting row from excel file and using row as parameter for SQL query SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to pass a list of items as parameters in a Microsoft SQL server query. I used pandas to read an excel file to get the list. When I run the script the error I get is `sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: List argument must consist only of tuples or dictionaries`.

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from datetime import date
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

def query_database(sg_items):
    end_date = date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    start_date = (date.today() - datetime.timedelta(days=90)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

    cnxn = create_engine(connection string)
    QUERY = f"""
     Select something,
            something_else,
            datetime
     from table
     where datetime between '{start_date}' and '{end_date}'
           and something IN ('{sg_items}')
     UNION
        (Select something,
            something_else,
            datetime
         from other_table
         where datetime between '{start_date}' and '{end_date}'
           and something IN ('{sg_items}')
     """
    df = pd.read_sql_query(QUERY, cnxn, params=sg_items)
    print(df)


def get_sg_list(input_file):
    df = pd.read_excel(input_file)
    processed_data = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        service_group = row["Service Group"]
        processed_data.append(service_group)
    print(processed_data)
    return processed_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_file_name = "file.xlsx"  # Replace with the actual input file name
    output_file_name = "file.xlsx"  # Replace with the desired output file name

    sg_list = get_sg_list(input_file_name)
    query_database(sg_list)
```

this runs through the `get_sg_list` function, and returns a list formatted like so.

```
['something_1', 'something_2', 'something_3, 'something_4', 'something_5', 'something_6']
```

I get the error when trying to pass that list through the params in the `pd.read_sql_query` function. I understand it's looking for a dictionary or tuple, but I only need the list as there aren't any other items I need to insert as a parameter.

Comment: Do you want to pass one row of 6 columns, or 6 rows of one column? Either way, just convert your list to a list of tuples with one column or whatever you need

Comment: I want to pass it as a list, since that what the sql server parameter formatting is. The query needs to get data for all items in that list. Maybe sqlalchemy isn't what I want to use here.

Comment: Did you try something like: `[('something_1',), ('something_2',)]` ? ie. list of tuples

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75102327/2144390